# Swift - Go to view when App enters background

Tags: ios, swift, background, appdelegate

How do I make my app go to a view when it detects that it enters the background? I have an authentication screen and I want that the user has to authenticate again when he comes back to the app. (Something like in 1password)

I tried to do something in appDelegate, but I just got a lot of errors.

```
let mapViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainVC") as? MainVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: false)
```

This is what I have tried to implement in applicationWillResignActive, but I got the error that appDelegate has no member called storyboard.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you have to refer UIStoryboard *storyboard ..... in your app delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move to rootview controller and write this code in this function:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    if let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as?UINavigationController {
        navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed. It works perfectly.